# Can't update Composite data with wcf ria servics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have entity MyTab which has composite property MyList.
WCF generates code fors MyTab for update like:

```
public void UpdateMyTab(MyTab currentMyTab) 
{          
    this.ObjectContext.MyTabs
                      .AttachAsModified(currentMyTab, 
                                        this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentMyTab));
}
```

When only composite data changed, MyTab data not changed,  then submit changes, I will get error **"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: original."** because no orginal for MyTab. changeset will have 2 item: MyTab and MyList.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check first the return value of **GetOriginal** if its null, before callling **AttachAsModified**. If **GetOriginal** returns null you should **Attach** the entity only to the ObjectContext. I don´t tested it but i would update your method to the following.

```
public void UpdateMyTab(MyTab currentMyTab) {          
  var original = this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentMyTab);

  if (original != null) {
    this.ObjectContext.MyTabs.AttachAsModified(currentMyTab, original);
  }
  else {
    this.ObjectContext.MyTabs.Attach(currentMyTab);
  }
}
```